# Copying UIButtons frame gives wrong position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, frame

I want to create another UIView / UIButton on an UIButton so I'm getting its' frame and use it in declaration of another UIView but It creates like below screenshot (with blue view). By the way, button is created on storyboard.

I'm using Xcode 9.1 and iOS 11.1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIView *picker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_mButton.frame];
    picker.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview: picker];
}
```

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qiqml.png)
[Screnshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd8r6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the proper frames are not calculated in `viewDidLoad`. You can try to make `picker` a property and adjust its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *picker;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.picker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_mButton.frame];
    self.picker.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview: self.picker];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.picker.frame = _mButton.frame;
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

But off course using storyboard and autolayout would probably be the best sollution if you have this possibility.

Comment: are you using the bounds to set the frame?  If you do this:     self.picker.frame = _mButton.frame the frame will probably not be correct as the buttons position is not at x=0 and y= 0

Comment: Can I just call it on ViewWillAppear? I think that will be the solution but It doesn't work also.

Comment: No I was using _mButton.frame

Comment: When I use bounds it is appearing on top left corner.

Comment: Great. Its because the frame of the button is in relation to its superview. So the x and y will have differenet values. When you want this picker to cover your button you will need the x and y to both be zero. This you will get by using bounds instead of frame.

Comment: But How can I assign it to view on button. I mean like covering button. I don't want it show up on top left.

Comment: Doesn't this happen now, after using the buttons bounds? How does it look now?

Comment: My new view appears on left top of screen. I want it just above button. so coordinates need to be same.

Comment: Ahh sorry, my bad.. I was taking for granted the view where a subview of the button. Now I see what you where trying to do. So then you where actually right about using the frame not the bounds. :-) So the problem still remains the same :-(

Comment: I have changed my answer to using frame. Does it still not work with this?

Comment: It is working now. Actually, This is my test project, I can't post my main project here but It has problem in there still. I need to examine it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. Good luck! :-)